# Xamarin - NetStandard and Android

Tags: xamarin

I have a project (A) which is a NetStandard 2.0 project. I also have an Xamarin Android Library project (B) which uses project A. I want to make project B a nugget (Azure DevOps) so I can install it in multiple projects.

When I compile on my local computer, everything is fine. However, the Azure pipeline always come out with this error "***Package XYZ is not compatible with monoandroid90 (MonoAndroid,Version=v9.0). Package XYZ 2022.5.13.1 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)***". Package XYZ is a .netStandard2.0 project because it is also (mainly) used within my base Xamarin Project.

XYZ contains an Interface which I implement in my Android project (B) (my base Xamarin Project uses it via DependencyServices).

The only way I can use it in other projects right now is to add the compiled .dll manually.

Anything I'm not seeing here ? Made numerous searches but I'm still clueless.

Comment: You might have to make a nuget that includes different compilations for different platforms. AFAIK, this will not be an issue in Maui, as both cross-platform and platform-specific are based on .Net 6.

Comment: I've forced using nuget 5.8 (task : NuGetToolInstaller@1 inputs: versionSpec: 5.8). It has solve my error. However, I am now stuck with "error MSB4057: Target "pack" does not exists in the project."

Comment: The problem error MSB4057 might be caused by not importing the NuGet.Build.Packaging.props and NuGet.Build.Packaging.targets in your project file correctly. You can check the import code if it is right or not.